# Gathering rate of return from yfinance API

Tags: python, excel, pandas, data-analysis, yfinance

[Picture of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRwFz.png)

Looking at my data I am trying to create a new column in a separate dataset that gives the ticker and the rate of return calculated by taking the open price of the first observation for a ticker and the last observation for that same ticker to take the close price and use those two numbers to calculate for my rate of return.

Comment: I'll try to answer your question, but can you give us more feedbacks on what you have already tried, and where you got stuck?

Comment: I tried to take the rate of return of each observation and then cumulate them but the open price is different from the close in many so that does not work. I was thinking that it would be possible to compare ticker symbols so that if a ticker symbol was not the same as the next observation then gather the close for that stock then the next new stock gather the open and repeat the process. The problem also is there are instances of the same 3 columns of data being grabbed next to each other but that is because it was gathered from insider trade data so it means multiple insiders traded that day

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using this function and tell me if it achieves your purpose?

```py
def calculate_return_rate(df):
    df_ordered = df.sort_values(by=["date"])
    df_last_close = df_ordered.groupby(["Ticker"]).agg("last")["close"]
    df_first_open = df_ordered.groupby(["Ticker"]).agg("first")["open"]
    return (df_last_close - df_first_open)/df_first_open
```

Comment: I got a weird error can would you care if I discussed with you over email about this, mine is patmcguigan98@gmail.com. If other social media works or text works let me know. I have an idea for this specific solution (dont know if it will work) and will need help later but I would love to explain my objective for this analysis to see if you would be interested in collaborating since the I have done blind investing without concrete analytical results and have made profitable returns but with a clearer understanding will make more consistent results.